# Subsetting a vector with 0s and 1s like seq(3) using [c(0,0,1)]

Tags: r, subset

I tried to subset my vector with `[c(0,0,1,0,1...)]`, but it returned a vector of 1s for each "1" in the binary vector I intended to use as a slicer, not the expected values which were to be picked out of the vector to the left.

```
seq(3)[as.logical(c(0,0,1))]
```

Works fine, but

```
seq(3)[c(0,0,1)]
```

returns 1, which I didn't expect. 
Just trying to understand how or why it's returning 1's instead of pulling the value that coincides with TRUE or 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is treating `c(0,0,1)` as a vector of position indicies.

Edit: by this I mean it is taking the 0th element twice then the 1st. Nothing in the 0th element so you get a single number which is the first element of your sequence, the number 1.

If you wanted it to be treated as your question suggests you could convert to a logical with `as.logical`

```
seq(3)[as.logical(c(0,0,1))]
# [1] 3
```

Comment: I don't think it's selecting from the sequence, I think its returning 1 meaning TRUE.  My real vector is much longer, I get a 1 for each 1 value in the slicer (the vector on the right).

Comment: There is actually no such thing as the "0th element" in R.  You probably know that, but your wording makes it sound like there is one.

Comment: you can check that `x[c(0,0,1)]` does pick the first element if you `rev(seq(3))`. You would see 3 appear instead.

@RichardScriven True, but you can attempt to subset using `x[0]` which gives you a zero length vector as a result

Comment: so you're saying 0 doesn't evaluate to FALSE in this case so it gets skipped and I am left out with 1s.

Comment: that is correct, the `as.logical` coerces 0 to FALSE and 1 to TRUE